# How do i delete downloaded file in using cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to delete a downloaded file before my next text execution but not able to find a way
how can I delete the downloaded file

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The configuration option `"trashAssetsBeforeRuns": true` is by default true, so unless you have already changed it, that's not the answer you're looking for.

Please be aware that it only applies to `cypress run` (headless) mode, ref [cypress.d.ts](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/9dacb106a93d98790273809f9ca4ade7e764858d/cli/types/cypress.d.ts#L2594) (confirmed with a simple test).

Also be aware of the `downloadsFolder` configuration option which defaults to `/cypress/downloads`. Outside the project, use the full path.

---

For `cypress open` the recipe [local-download-spec.js](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/7d4751c79c0b755ea4d8d02cf2a9b12a255f8a1d/examples/testing-dom__download/cypress/integration/local-download-spec.js#L17) gives you an example.

**Test**

```js
import { deleteDownloadsFolder } from './utils'
...
beforeEach(deleteDownloadsFolder)
...
```

**Utils**

```js
export const deleteDownloadsFolder = () => {
  const downloadsFolder = Cypress.config('downloadsFolder')
  cy.task('deleteFolder', downloadsFolder)
}
```

**Task in /cypress/plugins/index.js**

```js
const { rmdir } = require('fs')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    deleteFolder(folderName) {
      console.log('deleting folder %s', folderName)

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rmdir(folderName, { maxRetries: 10, recursive: true }, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return reject(err)
          }
          resolve(null)
        })
      })
    },
  })
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and it worked perfectly for me the first time. However I needed to also implement a check for the folder becuase if the folder does not exist this code will fail.

Answer (score 5):

You can add [this configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Downloads) to cypress.json: `"trashAssetsBeforeRuns": true`

Answer (score 2):

The quickest solution is to use [cypress-delete-downloads-folder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-delete-downloads-folder)
 npm package. Just several lines added to your Cypress configuration files would allow cleaning the folder from your tests with one command:

```js
cy.deleteDownloadsFolder()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with cy.exce()
Example
`cy.exec("find . -name " + <downloadDirectory> + "file");`
`cy.exec("cd " + <downloadDirectory> + ' ' + "&& rm -rf *");`

Answer (score 0):

@Rosen Mihaylov
here's correct example, you just missed a few brackets and lines

**Task in /cypress/plugins/index.js**

```js
    /// <reference types="cypress" />
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    
    const { rmdir } = require('fs')
    
    
    /**
     * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
     */
    module.exports = (on, config) => {
        // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
        // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
    
        // register utility tasks to read and parse Excel files
        on('task', {
            deleteFolder(folderName) {
                console.log('deleting folder %s', folderName)
    
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    rmdir(folderName, { maxRetries: 10, recursive: true }, (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err)
    
                            return reject(err)
                        }
    
                        resolve(null)
                    })
                })
            },
        })
    }
```

Comment: It's the same answer as above.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Year, it is. But I'm saying here was a few mistakes with missing brackets and line, such as:

```javascript
     on('task', {

```