# how can I delete a file to cypress?

Tags: javascript, exec, cypress, delete-file

I want to delete a file in cypress. the page that I test , there s a download button . I download a file to a directory. end of the test, I want to delete the file .

Could you please help me?

Comment: You can look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68176905/how-do-i-delete-downloaded-file-in-using-cypress